# how can I use ReactNative WebView component to show a specific part of a webpage in my Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, react-native

I want to use ReactNative webView component in my android app and show just a specific part of a web-page. for example I want to show the contents specified by the red rectangle in the image below:

[image: A github User]

and I don't need the other parts of the webpage.
I can show the whole page by the code below:

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: https://github.com/TrySound }}
  style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
/>
```

but don't know how to show just the contents in the red rectangle. Can anyone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView isn't going to work in your situation. Github does have a RESTful API. You can make a GET request for a username. You'll recieve a JSON object and the information you want will be under bio.

https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user

You can use the fetch api to get your bio

```
function getBio(){
  return fetch('https://api.github.com/users/trysound')
  .then(function(response) { return response.json();})
  .then(function(data) {return data.bio;});
}
```

and to access the result of the api request you can do the following

```
getBio().then(function(bio){
    // insert your code here to handle the string for your bio on github
    console.log(bio);
});
```